# Code Coverage on Android using Appium

Tags: android, appium

Is there any way to integrate developer code to existing TestNG project for code coverage on Android?
I wanted to check for the code coverage for my automated scripts created on Appium, but developer code and automation code belongs to different project

Answer (score -2):

Appium is a UI level automation tool. It doesn't and shouldn't know any thing inside the code. Its not white box testing. So you can't measure code coverage as such with appium. You have to resort to unit testing tools like JUnit.

Comment: Is there any way by which I can import my existing test script written in Appium to Android project? Can we convert appium project into a lib file and import directly to the android project so that I can use my test cases written in Appium to inspect the coverage of development code?

Comment: It's possible to track the coverage report for appium. Here's the commit that help to fulfill this feature by supporting androidCoverage. https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/1889

Comment: why the downvote? This could have been added much later than when I posted the answer.

Comment: Black-box testing does not necessarily mean no code coverage, we used to do manual testing only to gather the code coverage data that can't be get form unit testing.